# Adding port forwardings programmatically on a ControlMaster SSH session

Tags: security, ssh, port-forwarding, vnc, multiplexing

I just found out about the ControlMaster/ControlPath feature of OpenSSH, which allows you to use a single SSH connection to run multiple terminals.

As I often use SSH to use port forwarding to get encrypted and authenticated VNC sessions I instantly recognized that you can't add port forwardings to a remote server to which you already have an established connection. This sucks.

Sometimes later I found out that you can circumvent this limitation by typing ~C in a running SSH terminal session. This opens up a command-line which allows you to add or remove port forwardings.

My quesion now is: How can I add port forwardings on an existing SSH session which is using the ControlMaster/ControlPath feature, without the need to have access to a terminal session inside that SSH session. I need this to enable my script which starts a secure tunneled VNC connection for me to add and later remove its port forwardings.

(I know I could use a terminal multiplexer such as GNU Screen or tmux, actually I'm doing this already. But I like the idea of using just one SSH session for serveral reasons.)

Comment: I will be interseted in seeing if you find a way to do this, but I suspect you will not. Programatically controling the properties of an SSH session you are not actually a part of seems like a huge security problem.

Comment: Nonsense! How does programmatically controlling the properties of an SSH session introduce a huge security problem? The solution is really quite simple: http://serverfault.com/a/340361/93109

Comment: The question is now only asking about adding port-forwardings so it does better match the accepted answer. I asked a question on how to remove them afterwards here: http://serverfault.com/q/457295/50950

Comment: @Caleb it all depends who "you" is.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's quite simple, actually. Simply add the ctl_cmd `-O forward` to your existing command, thus:

```
ssh -M -L5555:localhost:22 remotehost
```

becomes:

```
ssh -O forward -M -L5555:localhost:22 remotehost
```

The [`ssh` man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh) discusses the `-O ctl_cmd` option:

```
-O ctl_cmd
        Control an active connection multiplexing master process.  When the -O option is
        specified, the ctl_cmd argument is interpreted and passed to the master process.
        Valid commands are: “check” (check that the master process is running), “forward”
        (request forwardings without command execution), “exit” (request the master to
        exit), and “stop” (request the master to stop accepting further multiplexing
        requests).
```

This, of course, assumes you've either enabled `ControlMaster yes` in your `~/ssh/config` file or `-M` on the command line.

Comment: Could you please try to answer the related question here: http://serverfault.com/q/457295/50950