# Removing port forwardings programmatically on a ControlMaster SSH session

Tags: security, ssh, port-forwarding, multiplexing

Quite a while ago I got an [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/340361/50950) telling me how to add a port-forwarding on a running SSH ControlMaster process. To know that helps a lot, but I'm still missing a way to remove such a port forwarding after I don't need that anymore.

As far as I know, you can do that through the internal command key sequence on normal connections, this seems to be disabled for ControlMaster clients. Even if that would be possible I would need a solution which I can automatize with scripts, which is surely not so easy this way.

Is there a way to do it? And is it easily automatizable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [my previous answer](https://serverfault.com/a/340361/93109) notes, the [ssh man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh) explains the `-O ctl_cmd` in detail, where `ctl_cmd` is one of `check`, `forward`, `cancel`, or `exit`.

```
-O ctl_cmd
        Control an active connection multiplexing master process.  When the -O option is
        specified, the ctl_cmd argument is interpreted and passed to the master process.
        Valid commands are: “check” (check that the master process is running), “forward”
        (request forwardings without command execution), “exit” (request the master to
        exit), and “stop” (request the master to stop accepting further multiplexing
        requests).
```

You can use the `ctl_cmd`'s to accomplish the automation you want for your scripts. You'll need to first create a `ControlMaster` socket with the `-S` like and ssh to the remotehost like this:

```
ssh -v -M -S/tmp/controlmaster-remotehost remotehost
```

and then from your local machine you can `forward` and `cancel` ports as you like. You can forward multiple ports with one command:

```
ssh -O forward -S/tmp/controlmaster-remotehost -L5555:localhost:22 -L3333:localhost:22 remotehost
```

and/or handle them one at a time:

```
ssh -O cancel  -S/tmp/controlmaster-remotehost -L5555:localhost:22 remotehost
ssh -O cancel  -S/tmp/controlmaster-remotehost -L3333:localhost:22 remotehost
```

I created a [gist with a side-by-side session](https://gist.github.com/raw/4265549/999d90b8f85190a41eed00e4d60d5d22da6c67b9/ssh-controlmaster-side-by-side.log) showing the `ssh -O ctl_cmd` in action; with port `forward`/`cancel` from localhost on the left side, and the output of ssh connected to remotehost on the right side:

https://gist.github.com/raw/4265549/999d90b8f85190a41eed00e4d60d5d22da6c67b9/ssh-controlmaster-side-by-side.log

These commands are only available as of [OpenSSH 6.0](http://www.openssh.org/txt/release-6.0):

```
 * ssh(1): support for cancelling local and remote port forwards via the
   multiplex socket. Use ssh -O cancel -L xx:xx:xx -R yy:yy:yy user@host"
   to request the cancellation of the specified forwardings
 * support cancellation of local/dynamic forwardings from ~C commandline
```

If you have an earlier version you'll need to upgrade. If you're on Mac OS X you can [install macports](http://www.macports.org/install.php) and then [upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9644576/462302) using: `sudo port install  openssh` which will install it into `/opt/local/bin`.

Comment: In OpenSSH 5.8p1 the `cancel` command seems not to be existent. When trying to use it on an active ControlMaster process I'm getting the following message: `Invalid multiplex command.`

Comment: 6.0p1 seems to be the first version which supports that command. It's not available on my current OS.

Comment: Yes, you're right it's only available in version 6.0p1 and above. I assume you're using Mac OS X, in which case you can get the newer version with macports. I'll update my answer with the info.

Comment: Actually I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 and don't trust the updater, nor seems that version to be available through backports. I guess I have to reinstall my system sometime soon.

Comment: Why don't you trust the Ubuntu updater? I have consistently good experiences with it. I think it's a good idea to do a fresh re-install anyway so then you get the advantage of doing an LVM-based install in 12.10 which is a good thing.